# Finding Tables in Current Word Document

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to edit tables within a Word Document using VBA. The following MsgBox returns 0 even though there are several tables within the document. Elsewhere in the macro, I am successfully editing a value in the Word Document with:

```
With WA.ActiveDocument
Set myRange = .Content
With myRange.Find
.Execute Findtext:="Sally", ReplaceWith:=FirstName, Replace:=1
EndWith
EndWith
```

> MsgBox (WA.ActiveDocument.Content.Tables.Count)

Answer (score 0):

Just use inside the With statement(if they are actual tables)

```
MsgBox .Tables.Count
```

You can verify by switching to the Word document itself and putting the following `Msgbox ActiveDocument.Tables.Count` in the ThisDocument part of the ActiveDocument. If the answer is still 0 then you are not working with Word Tables.

Comment: With this, I get runtime error 424, "Object Required"

Comment: From Msgbox ActiveDocument.Tables.Count ?

Comment: And with Msgbox     .Tables.Count inside the With ?

Comment: A messageBox with zero.

Comment: At the end of the macro, after I'm finding and replacing a number of values (these values are not within tables)

Comment: Is this code placed in Excel or in Word? Cos I am wondering if actually is something like WA.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169619/discussion-between-qharr-and-sartorialist).